# custom uitabbar in monotouch similar to voice memos app

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitabbar

I am trying to replicate the feature in voice memos app that uses a custom UiTabBar displaying a slider (showing how long and where the the audio currently is) and two buttons (delete and share). I am struggling to find answers as to generate a similar tabbar that can control the content shown in the background. I would appreciate any comments or suggestions on how to achieve this with monotouch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, what you are seeing in the voice memos app is not a tab bar. It is a custom UIView that is at the bottom of the screen.

Create a custom view to put at the bottom, and give it delegate call backs to your controller that also controls your other content. When a button is pressed have you view call back to the delegate and then the delegate can act on it.You may also want to give your custom view an external property so that you can have your controller update the position of the slider.

Hoep this is of some help to you :)

Comment: thanks for this, but would it remain in the bottom even if I am scrolling up and down in the main controller in the background? Not sure how this would work....

Comment: Well your controller would have a table view an this bottom view. It's table view would take up the top x% of the screen and the bottom view would take up the remaining (100-x)% of the screen. So you custom view would always be stationary at the bottom, and your table view at the top. :)

Comment: thanks again, but I am struggling to get this to work. I would really appreciate a very simple code example to point me to the right direction :)

Comment: ok, although george's answer is correct, in the end i created a `SliderView` and added it to the `SetToolBarItems` to show just above my `UIToolBar`. So in essence I did the following:  `SliderView sv = GeneratePlaybackSlider();
   UIBarButtonItem svButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem();
   svButtonItem.CustomView = sv;
   
   this.SetToolbarItems (new UIBarButtonItem[] {svButtonItem}, true);`